# catching exceptions inside PowerShell DSC resources

Tags: powershell, dsc

The following code when executed outside of a powershell resource works without any problems:

```
    try {
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
            < call function >
        }
        catch {
            $ErrorMessage = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $_.ErrorDetails).ms

        }
        finally {
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
        }
}
```

However, when I put this inside a DSC resource, when the exception gets raised the exception handler is ignored. I suspect that this might have something to do with the have that dsc using windows remoting.

Comment: The missing text at the end of my question has now been added.

Comment: Generating exceptions inside configurations doesn't really make sense.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My question was not about generating exception, but what to do if they arise.